# Nexmo inbound sms

Tags: java, spring-boot, vonage

i have a question about Nexmo SMS and about nexmo java client.

I have one virtual number, and I want to send from it to person A. Also, I have send and specyfing that it was sent from "Ajris". Then, i would like to send another message to that person and specify that it was sent from "Iris". So person A has two messages, one from Ajris and one from Iris. When she replies to the message, how am I supposed to know which message did she responde to? As I have checked there aren't any fields in InboundMessage API in Nexmo which allows me to connect received message to the sent one. Is there any chance to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because person A sends the SMS from a phone using a native client, you can not control the information being sent with the SMS message. There is no information associated with that SMS, so there is no data you can use to correlate it to the message being replied to.

One way to get around that limitation is to use two Nexmo Virtual Numbers instead of one, so when person A replies, you can correlate based on the Nexmo Virtual Number used.

Answer (score 1):

For what you're looking to do - you would need multiple Nexmo Numbers. You can then pull the `to` field out of the Inbound SMS and use that to map between the two distinct individuals.